# LDAP encrypt attribute that extends userpassword

Tags: ldap

In my current LDAP schema I have an objectclass (let's call it *group*) that has 2 attributes that extend userpassword. Like this:

```
attributeType ( groupAttributes:12 NAME 'groupPassword1'        
    SUP userPassword
    SINGLE-VALUE )

attributeType ( groupAttributes:13 NAME 'groupPassword2'        
        SUP userPassword
        SINGLE-VALUE )
```

*group* extends organisation so already has a userpassword attribute. If I use that to enter a new group using PHPLDAPAdmin it uses SSHA (by default) and encrypts/hashes the password I entered. But the passwords I entered for groupPassword1 en groupPassword2 don't get encrypted.

Is there a way to make it so that those attributes are encrypted too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just resolved trouble like this by creating new objects with the auxiliary class [simpleSecurityObject](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4524#section-3.9) (I've used [organizationalRole](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2256#section-7.9) as the structural class, but anything will do) as children of the object that needs more than one class of passwords. Note however that userPassword is a multivalued attribute and can contain several values.

- cn=group,ou=Groups,...

  - cn=extrapassword,cn=group,ou=Groups,...
  - cn=additionalpassword,cn=group,ou=Groups,...

or:

```
dn: cn=group,ou=Groups,...
objectClass: ...
userPassword: password1
userPassword: password2
...
```

Comment: Could you work out further how this would work exactly? I can't find much info on simpleSecurityObject. Is it something like this?
`objectclass ( groupObjectclasses:1 NAME 'groupWithPW'
    SUP group
    STRUCTURAL )`
Then I have one password, but I need two? Or do I just repeat this step and make another objectclass that does `SUP groupWithPW`?